# How to create an input checkbox dynamically in a proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to create an checkbox using an  success function from ajax, 
all the data in the table is being created properly but my input checkbox is not appearing on my table but if I change to a button it works, just checkbox does not work.
How can I fix it?
Thanks.

```
         function createTableByJqueryEach(data)
        {


            var eTable=`<table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-light"><tr>
                <th scope="col">Nome da Instituição</th>
                <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
                <th scope="col">UF</th>
                <th scope="col">Responsável</th>
                <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Nota</th>
                <th scope="col">IAD Conh.</th>
                <th scope="col">IAD Apli.</th>
                <th scope="col">Enviar Ubc</th>
                </tr>
                </thead><tbody>`

            $.each(data,function(index, row){                
                eTable += "<tr>";
                $.each(row,function(key,value){     
                    if(value['ubc'] !== undefined){
                        eTable += "<tr><td>"+value['ubc']['name']+"</td><td>" + value['ubc']['partner']['title'] + "</td><td>"+value['ubc']['uf']+"</td><td>"+
                            value['ubc']['coordinator']+"</td><td>"+value['ubc']['email']+"</td><td>"+ parseFloat(value['nf'].toFixed(3)) +"</td><td>"+
                                parseFloat(value['ap_grade'].toFixed(1))+"</td><td>"+parseFloat(value['kn_grade'].toFixed(1))+"</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td>";
                    }                   
                });
                eTable += "</tr>";
            });
            eTable +="</tbody></table>";
            $('#eachTable').html(eTable);
            }


    $('#taxo_id').click(function(){
        var radio_option = $("input[type='radio']:checked"); 

        var ubcs = JSON.parse('{{ubcs}}')


        $.ajax({
            url:"/api/v1/oportuniy/diogoreturn/",
            type:"GET",
            data: {
                option:radio_option.val(),
                oportunity: '{{oportunity.id}}',
                filter:'{{filter_oportunity.id}}',
                ubcs:ubcs
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                createTableByJqueryEach(data);                

            },
            error: function(data){                    
                swal({
                    title:'Atenção!',
                    text:data['responseJSON']['error'],
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,
                    dangerMode: true,
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox"> in this line check box is in single quotes

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, I guess since buttons doesn't need attributes you don't have a problem.

Comment: I tried single quotes but did not work

Comment: It looks like your quotes are messing JS. Just try to escape them 
parseFloat(value['ap_grade'].toFixed(1))+"</td><td>"+parseFloat(value['kn_grade'].toFixed(1))+"</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\"></td>";

Comment: thanks guys for your help I changed my code a little bit and the problem was some missing quotes.